# dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer - android

Tags: android, android-studio

When I want to run my app on some smartphones that have 4.4.2 or 4.4.4 android version I got this error :

```
/BufferQueue: [com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.Launcher] dequeueBuffer: can't dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count
```

my `gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*.*.*"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/felipecsl/m2repository/master' }
   // maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()

}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
  // my libraries...
}
```

Comment: Same problem I am also facing. How to avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug with the Google Play version. You can try to disable hardware acceleration in Android manifest to remove this error.

Comment: disabling hardware acceleration will lead to UI related issues (no shadows, jerky scroll etc) on plenty of devices.